# In probability, does P(A) = P(AB) + P(AB')?

Tags: probability

Let A and B be events.
It seems to make sense to be that the probability that A occurs is equal to the probability that A and B both occur PLUS the probability that A occurs and B does not.  I haven't been able to find this identity in my textbook though.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Answer (score 2):

$$P(A)=P(A\Omega)=P(A\cap (B\cup B'))=P((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B'))=P(AB)+P(AB'). $$

Where the last equality stands because AB and AB' have no intersections.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. If you write it is conditional probability, this should be apparent. Note that $P(AB) = P(A|B)P(B)$ and refer to Bayes conditional probability rule.